# Fail to process request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey

Tags: sonarqube

I am facing the issue with SQ scan of few of my projects.

```
 2017.11.20 20:26:36 ERROR web[AV/cUNmR+tiFEjO/AAAg][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.org.app:app&projectName=ReactorProject

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readPart(ServletRequest.java:102) at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readInputStreamParam(ServletRequest.java:85) at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.paramAsInputStream(ValidatingRequest.java:83)
at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:10

 .......................

Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2919)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3215)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1145)

Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:308)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2871)
        ... 52 common frames omitted



Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:718)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1063)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:257)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:574)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:571)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:595)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:613)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:874)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:854)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

I am using the embedded H2 database.

Sonar version is 6.5 and installed on Windows 7.

The file upload completes successfully when the compressed content is < 50 KB in size (I am guessing, based on how it has worked out for me).

This always fails for me:

```
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 1022ms, dir size=384 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 3019ms, zip size=190 KB
```

Anything beyond that fails with the above exception.

Are you aware of any setting that limits the size of the file being uploaded to SQ server?

Any help will be high appreciated.

Comment: are you starting sonar manually?

Comment: Yes. using StartSonar.bat

Comment: Looks more like a timeout. Are both components on the same machine? Never use the H2 database in production environments.

Comment: Yes, running on the same machine. I even moved to MySQL, but the problem persists.

Comment: Any solution. facing same issue